# CLion: Clangd not found

Tags: clion, clangd

[image]

I had to set up the executable in CLion today. Now the autocorrect is not working anymore and I'm receveibing the error message:
Clangd is not found at D:\Programme\CLion\CIDR\clion\bin\clang\win\clangd.exe

Clangd seems to be in a different folder:
D:\Programme\CLion\bin\clang\win\clangd.exe

How can I fix this issue and get my autocorrect back?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that something goes wrong with CLion installation.
At first, would you reinstall the CLion.

Be sure that you have no `.idea` folder inside the `D:\Programme\CLion`. Remove it, if it is.

If the problem still exists, add the entry
`-DCLANGD_PATH=D:\Programme\CLion\bin\clang\win\clangd.exe`
to CLion VM options (`Help | Edit Custom VM Options`)

To get an effect, please, restart CLion.